# Which user's data can I access through fql?

Tags: facebook-fql

Okay, total noob question:

I want to understand what FQL can do, so I know if it can be useful to me before I try to learn it. From browsing Facebook's documentation I could not understand the following:

With FQL, can I search among ALL registered users for e.g. users of a certain age and gender from a certain region? Or can I only search among my friends?

Please provide a quote from and a link to official or otherwise reliable documentation along with your "yes" or "no".

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook API only returns things that are visible to the owner of the `access_token` when making a query. FQL has the added requirement that the first field in your `WHERE` portion of the query must be indexable. These are marked with a ★ in [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql).

For your example of querying the `user` table, your query must have one of the following immediately after `WHERE`: `uid IN`, `username IN`, `name IN` or `third_party_id IN`. The easiest way to get a list of these is by passing a subquery to get the current user's friends via `WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())`. There are some other, more complex ways to get at a list of ids.

As for your app, it's going to be very hard to search for this reliably. The user's `age`, `gender` and `location` are up to the user to populate. The user can choose not to populate these, or keep them private. If these items are private, keep in mind that this filtering takes place *after* your query completes, so it is possible that all results returned by your query will be filtered out.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this. How does this answer my question about which users I can search?

Comment: Short answer: You *might* be able to search users whose `uids` you know or can find through other means. Facebook search is not developer friendly.